# How to post data for WebView android

Tags: android, http-post, android-webview

I need to post data to Webview. 
I found from some of the links the below code:

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(webview);
 String url = "http://www.example.com";
 String postData = username=my_username&password=my_password";
 webview.postUrl(url",EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

But in my android studio I see EncodingUtils as deprecated 
Can anyone help me what is the alternative for EncodingUtils to post data to Android WebView?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try like below...

Java:

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(webview);

 String url = "http://www.example.com";

 String postData = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_username, "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_password, "UTF-8");
 webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

Kotlin:

```
val webview = WebView(this)
setContentView(webview)

val url = "http://www.example.com"

val postData = "username=${URLEncoder.encode(my_username, "UTF-8")}" +
"&password=${URLEncoder.encode(my_password, "UTF-8")}"
webview.postUrl(url, postData.toByteArray())
```

Comment: for Kotlin use toByteArray instead of getBytes

Comment: nice. also, if your parameters are in a hashmap, you can simplify to this: `val postData = params.toList().joinToString(separator = "&") { "${it.first}=${URLEncoder.encode(it.second, "UTF-8")}" }`

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple workaround.

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html>" +
    "<body onload='document.frm1.submit()'>" +
    "<form action='http://www.yoursite.com/postreceiver' method='post' name='frm1'>" +
    "  <input type='hidden' name='foo' value='12345'><br>" +
    "  <input type='hidden' name='bar' value='23456'><br>" +
    "</form>" +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>";
webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I know this is not the best method but this works.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add a few things to the answer as I had to work on same and found some info could help complete the answer to this question.

- First thing is the need for such a scenario. My need was that I am
  creating a payment gateway client for native applications in android.
- Second thing is that the URL you are opening needs to perform some
  operations right. Hence you must enable your **webView** to enable
  such operations or else things might not work. For example if your
  URL is executing some java script, than you must enable java script
  for your **webview**. This can be done as shown below :

  ```
     val set = webview.settings
     set.javaScriptEnabled = true
  ```

  Normally this will enable trivial things such as timers, returning results etc on your webview.
- Third thing is a case when your webView needs to call methods of your android app. This can be done by adding some JavaScript Interface as shown below :

  ```
      webview.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(), "Android")
  ```

  Where WebAppInterface() is a simple class which atleast one method annotated with **@JavascriptInterface** as shown below :

  ```
  class WebAppInterface() {

      @JavascriptInterface
      fun showToast(status: String) {
          //show toast here or handle status
      }
  }
  ```

  The name **Android** will be the one which will be injected into your URL as a variable and you can call the methods of your android WebAppInterace from that URL as shown below:

  Android.showToast("From WebPage")
- Last thing is your postURL method which is somewhat like :

  ```
      webview.postUrl(actionUrl, params.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
  ```

  This method has couple of things that it takes as default. First is that request type is taken as default **POST** as the name suggest.

Header content-type can be default taken as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and 
most important params it takes as **&** separated key value pairs as shown :

```
        val params = "MERCHANT_ADDR=" + addr + "&CHANNEL=android"
```

We must pass byteArray of this string which is shown in post URL callback.

Now after your API is hit and it in some cases loads a callback url, from that call back URL using the JavaScript Interface, you can return result to your application and close the **webview**.

I hope it helps people.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
You need to URL-encode the parameter value before sending it.

```
String postData = "fileContents=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileCon, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: how to pass username , password ??

Comment: you can do something like "postvar=value&foo=bar". Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: u mean to say : String postdata =  username=+URLEncoder.encode(my_username,"UTF-8") &   password=+URLEncoder.encode(my_password,"UTF-8"); webview.postUrl(url",postdata );

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here by trying to put a html body as a postData and not working,
try to put your string body as something below:

```
    val htmlCode = "https://ramdom.user.me"

    val postData = "{\n" +
            "\t\"token\": \"963966f649\"\n" + "}"

    webview.postUrl(htmlCode, postData.toByteArray())
```

I hope to save someone`s life. :-)