# Fetch user signed in details from a website hosted in an android Webview

Tags: android, session, authentication, webview

I created a Webview android app for my website so as to have an android version of my website. The website allows a user to sign in before proceeding to the website information.

Please, How do I fetch the user signed in details (e.g email) from the website in my Webview android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of the `WebView` using this function:

```
yourWebView.evaluateJavascript(
        "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
         new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                Log.d("HTML", html); 
                // Here you work with the content of the page which is stored in the 'html' variable
            }
    });
```

Since you are able to read the content of the page, you can either hide the data you want to read in the website in a hidden field (e.g. `<input type="hidden" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value="someone@example.org">`).

Or you can create a own `Activity` where the use can insert his email address, and then you can post the inserted email address on your website using the `WebView.postUrl(String url, byte[] postData)` function (e.g. `webView.postUrl("https://yourWebsite.com/index.php", "emailAddress=someone@example.org".getBytes());`).

Source: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
[how to get html content from a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)
[How to post data for WebView android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506246/how-to-post-data-for-webview-android)